# Simple Retirement Fund Using Loops

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to make a program that calculates the amount of money someone would have after retiring at 67 and started saving at the age the entered.

The program should show how much the save each year at a rate of 2.5% and then the total after the entered amount of years.

So far I got the income to display for each year but the total seems to be 2.5% more than what it needs to be.

```
int age = 0;
    double income;
    double total = 0;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How old are you? ");
    age = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.print("What is your annual income? ");
    income = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Age(years) Income($)");

    while(age < 68) {
        System.out.print(age + " " + income);
        income += (income * .025);
        total += income;
        age ++;
    }

    System.out.print("total($) " + total);

    keyboard.close();
```

I've been using 62 as my age and 60000 as the amount per year. But when I print the total instead of getting ~383000 I'm getting ~392000.

Answer (score 1):

you are not counting the last iteration 67-68 when you have <68 in the while loop
meaning when the age is 67 the loop doesn't run and therefore the last year's income is not calculated 
should be while(age<=68)